# How to generate a Graphite single stat for a counter

Tags: graphite

I have a counter metric the counts the number of errors thrown by my application.  I'm trying to use a single stat panel to show the number of errors thrown in the selected time period,  but failing miserably.

I've tried sumSeries (nonNegativeDerivative(myapp.count)) but this didn't work .

Any tips would be gratefully appreciated.

Nick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
integral(transformNull(myapp.count, 0))
```

Since it is a count, the integral will be just the sum of all counts over the selected period. The `transformNull` serves to sum 0 for times where no counts were collected.

Then in the grafana singlestat panel, select `max` as function value, so you will get the last value of the integral.

Comment: Great thanks I'll try that. How do I then extend it so create a value from multiple server instances? For example, say I had myapp.server1.count to myapp.serverN.count? In this case I'd need the total for the time period per server, and then add those totals together.

Comment: I'd try summing those series before performing the integral: `integral(transformNull(sumSeries(myapp.server[0-9].count), 0))`